# `journald` vs `systemd-journald` - are they the same notions?

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald

I am new to `systemd`.

I have read that along with `systemd` boot system comes [it's own logging daemon](https://sematext.com/blog/journald-logging-tutorial/#what-is-journald) - `journald`. But there is also a lot of mention of `systemd-journald` daemon [over the Internet](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-journald.service.html).

At first glance, I couldn't discern any differences between the two daemons. They appear to be aliases of each other. However, I might be mistaken.

Could someone please clarify and explain any distinctions between these two daemons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`journald` and `systemd-journald` are the same notion.

`journald` is often used as a shorthand for `systemd-journald`,
which is the logging component of the systemd system and service manager.

Systemd is a suite of software that provides fundamental building blocks for managing and controlling the Linux operating system.
It includes various components, including `systemd-journald`, which is responsible for collecting, storing, and retrieving log data.

`systemd-journald` is the name of the daemon process that runs `journald`. It is the specific instance of the `journald` daemon that is launched and managed by `systemd`.

`journald` is the concept of the logging component, while `systemd-journald` is the specific instance of the daemon responsible for executing the logging functionality.

`journald` and `systemd-journald` refer to the same daemon, and they are used interchangeably to denote the logging functionality provided by systemd.

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-journald.service.html

[journald.conf, journald.conf.d, journald@.conf — Journal service configuration files](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html#)

[Tutorial: Logging with journald](https://sematext.com/blog/journald-logging-tutorial/)

Comment: To clarify a bit further, systemd-journald _is the only journald implementation right now_ (and this is likely to remain the case, most developers who would be inclined to write an alternative recognize the numerous inherent issues with it as simply making it not worth it), so making a differentiation between the two concepts makes little sense, unlike with, for example, logind.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both are the same. `systemd-journald` is the name of the service running the `journald` daemon:

```
$ systemctl status systemd-journald
● systemd-journald.service - Journal Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-journald.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-03-29 14:25:45 IDT; 3 months 3 days ago
     Docs: man:systemd-journald.service(8)
           man:journald.conf(5)
 Main PID: 435 (systemd-journal)
   Status: "Processing requests..."
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 512)
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-journald.service
           └─435 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journald
```

And also the name of the command to run the daemon and the name of the daemon process.

```
$ ps -fC systemd-journald
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root       435     1  0 Mar29 ?        00:50:36 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journald
```